# Kitchen sink half-wall against brick: which layer to drywall?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, framing, cabinets, kitchen-sink

Relocating a kitchen sink to an exterior wall, I'll be building a 2x4 half-wall against the brick in which to run plumbing.  I'll then install cabinets in front of that wall.

Which layer to drywall?  I could drywall the brick and furring, or the stud half-wall, or both?

Also note that there'll be an outlet under the sink and a whip for the dishwasher.

I intend to use greenboard FWIW.

[image: kitchen sink half-wall, which later to drywall?]

Answer (score 1):

I  would do both ,foam insulation drywall, 2x4 , insulate ,drywall  Do not like the pipes on exterior wall drafts and  freeze up

Comment: My concerns with this, besides the fact that I've never seen it done anywhere, are a), making a vapor barrier sandwich, and b), losing the extra space that would allow you to run full batts of insulation in the 2x4 cavity, sneaking behind the 2" drain pipes into the furred area.

Comment: If you look at the brick joints seem  drafty,  1 inch or  3/4 foam with poly helps then drywall over that. Then do your wall pipes in 2x4 wall  would even insulate pipes you still have all your barriers.

Comment: If you run pex  you could at least have the water lines inside the cabnet on the sink base the it is inside away from drafts.